# Creative Cloud - Complete vs Complete for Students?

Tags: creative-cloud

So, I'm going to buy a Creative Cloud subscription in a few weeks to months. Since I'm a student, so I'm eligible for the special introductory option at 20 $ / month.

My question is if this offer includes exactly the same as the "normal" creative cloud full subscription. I't not like I'm gonna pass on this offer because of some missing features, but I would like to no if there's anything I'm missing out.

Also, does anyone know how long this special offer will be available? Would be a shame to come back in a month or so to realise it's no longer there ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product information as related to pricing, from a vendor and not design. You should contact the vendor directly if you have questions about their product pricing/services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same version of CC as the non-student deal and as far as this deal expiring, Adobe have been running it for quite a while now, so I would assume you should have a little while longer to make up your mind, but you never know.

As mentioned, though, a question much better suited for the Adobe forums.